# Ruby #split("") vs #chars on a string

Tags: ruby, string, split

What is the difference between #split and #chars in Ruby when splitting a string?

```
"Hello, World".split("")
#=> ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", ",", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]

"Hello, World".chars
#=> ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", ",", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
```

They both return an array, and they both include the blank space and punctuation.

Is there a scenario where one is preferable?

Comment: They have the same effect, so neither is preferable. You can say the same about a third option: `"Hello, World".split(//)`. Note that `"Hello, World".split` is commonly used, because it is equivalent to  `"Hello, World".split(/[ \t\n\r\f\v]+/)` because it splits on strings containing any number and combinations of spaces, tabs, newlines, form-feeds and so on.

Comment: One other thing, for `str = "Hello, World"`, suppose you write `str.chars.map(&:upcase) #=> ["H", "E", "L", "L", "O", ",", " ", "W", "O", "R", "L", "D"]`.  Like all methods in the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html) module, `map`'s receiver is an [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html), so under the covers Ruby uses [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-each) to execute `str.chars.each.map(&:upcase)`...

Comment: ... It's more efficient to simply use [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) which, when used without a block, returns an enumerator (rather than constructing a  temporary array). You should write `str.each_char.m` for all `Enumerable` methods `m`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What is the difference between `split` and `chars` [...]?

`string.chars` parses the underlying bytes to returns the string's characters, whereas `string.split('')` uses a regular expression to achieve the same.

As a result, `chars` is faster and more robust. It even works if the string contains invalid characters:

```
"foo\x80bar".chars
#=> ["f", "o", "o", "\x80", "b", "a", "r"]
```

Whereas `split` fails if the string is malformed (because the regex engine can't handle it):

```
"foo\x80bar".split('')
#=> ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

If I'm not mistaken, `split('')` is equivalent to `split(//)`.

> Is there a scenario where one is preferable?

`split('')` can be found in many tutorials. I assume this is because prior to Ruby 2.x, `chars` returned an enumerator. So in order to get an array you had to use *two* method calls:

```
string.chars.to_a
```

or a single call to: (which is also slightly shorter)

```
string.split('')
```

Nowadays, you'd use `chars` (or `each_char` for the pre-2.x behavior)

Answer (score 5):

You can use **split** for dividing strings into substrings based on a delimiter

For example:

```
"a/b-c".split('/') will return ["a", "b-c"]
```

**chars** instead returns an array of characters in string

```
"a/b-c".chars will return ["a", "/", "b", "-", "c"]
```

In conclusion, there are plenty of scenarios where one is more suitable than the other one.

Comment: Given the example, I assume the OP is only concerned about `split` when the argument is an empty string. If so, this doesn't answer the question. clockworkpc, please clarify. Also, why the rush to select an answer? You don't want to see other answers?

Comment: What about the last line of his question "Is there a scenario where one is preferable?" The above example is one scenario.

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry for the ambiguity of my OP, but SgtPepper got it right: What I meant by "is there a scenario...?" was this:

Is there a scenario — beyond this example — where #split is preferable #chars? i.e. Is there something I can do (or do better) one or the other?

SgtPepper provided such a response.

Comment: clockworkpc, that makes no sense. When `split`'s argument is anything other than an empty space, it's "preferable" to `chars` in the same way that it's preferable to, say, `upcase`: neither `split` nor `upcase` have `split`'s functionality in that case. "Preferable" should only be used when comparing two things that both get the job done.